# Create a history dataframe to save historical values python

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I need to create a history dataframe (history_df), in python, that stores the all the content of other dataset (current_df), that is being refreshed every hour.

The contents of the current_df are being erased with the new ones because its primary key is the Robot ID column, so that´s why I need the history_df to have everything.

For instance, if current_df has this data at 1:00 pm:

```
Robot ID      Distance to finish line (km)
AB2           2
FG3           7
GJ7           56
```

And like this at 2:00 pm:

```
Robot ID      Distance to finish line (km)
    AB2           0,5
    FG3           3
    GJ7           20
    HHV           2
```

I would need history_df to store all the rows on current_df:

```
Robot ID      Distance to finish line (km)
    AB2           2
    FG3           7
    GJ7           56
    AB2           0,5
    FG3           3
    GJ7           20
    HHV           2
```

Is there a way to do this?

I looked up the write_dataframe() function, but not sure if it removes duplicate values.

Thank you and kind regards.

Comment: You can append data frames with `pandas.concat`, just start with an empty frame for history_df and concat the current_df to history_df on each update.

Comment: The pyspark way of doing this is `df.write.mode("append"). ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should consider having a primary key (index) built of both `Robot ID` and a `timestamp` in `history_df`. This way concatinating new records from `current_df` will not mean a duplicate record, and also you will count with information on the moment of the record.

I recommend having something like this:

| Robot ID | Timestamp | Distance to finish line (km) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB2 | 2023-01-18 13:00:00 | 2 |
| FG3 | 2023-01-18 13:00:00 | 7 |
| GJ7 | 2023-01-18 13:00:00 | 56 |
| AB2 | 2023-01-18 14:00:00 | 0,5 |
| FG3 | 2023-01-18 14:00:00 | 3 |
| GJ7 | 2023-01-18 14:00:00 | 20 |
| HHV | 2023-01-18 14:00:00 | 2 |

By the way, as stated in the comment, you can achieve this by instantiating an empty `DataFrame` and "fill it up" iteratively through `pd.concat`:

```
import pandas as pd 

# Empty DataFrame
history_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Robot ID", "Timestamp", "Distance to finish line (km)")
```

And using concatinating each time with:

```
# assuming they have the same columns
history_df = pd.concat([history_df, current_df])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. Is there a way to make this work with a pyspark function?